# Need help on PHP/jQuery comments script

Tags: php, jquery

I asked this question previously but i didnt post the code. So here it goes...

```
<?php require(database.php); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.comment-wrap {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.reply {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment-wrap .replyLink {
    float: right;
}
.comment-wrap .comment {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.comment-wrap .img {
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".reply").hide();
        });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.replyButton').click(function() {
            $(".reply").show();
        });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$sql= "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result = $database->query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="comment-wrap">';
        echo '<div class="img">' . $row['img'] .'</div>';
        echo '<div class="comment">' . $row['comment'] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="replyLink">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="replyButton" ">Reply</a></div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="reply">
    Type your message: <br />
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label for="reply"></label>
            <textarea name="replyMessage" class="replyMessage" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
      </form>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on reply button reply class is expanded on all the comments which was hidden previously. But i want the reply class to expand only on that comment on which the user has clicked the reply button.

The content will be stored in MySQL database and retrieved through PHP. But here i just need help on jQuery part. I'm not asking for full code, just give me some hints so that i can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/jquery-show-hide-multiple-elements/

Give class "toggle" to any element you want to apply show/hide functionality and here's the JS

```
// Andy Langton's show/hide/mini-accordion - updated 23/11/2009
// Latest version @ http://andylangton.co.uk/jquery-show-hide

// this tells jquery to run the function below once the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

// choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
var showText='Show';
var hideText='Hide';

// initialise the visibility check
var is_visible = false;

// append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "toggle"
$('.toggle').prev().append(' (<a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>)');

// hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
$('.toggle').hide();

// capture clicks on the toggle links
$('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;

// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);

// toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
//$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
$(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');

// return false so any link destination is not followed
return false;

});
});
```

Comment: if i apply the toggle to reply class then still the reply class will expand on all the comments and not on the specific one.

Comment: There is even a demo in the link I posted which shows that only one element is shown, not all.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one element with the same id in the document so you can change id for the class

```
echo '<a href="#" class="replyButton" ">Reply</a></div>';
```

and use this jQuery code instead

```
$('.replyButton').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

this will dispay the next element after the parent. The parent is `.comment-wrap` and the next element is `.reply`